# "flutter" safest way to deal with XMLHttpRequest error handling

Tags: flutter, cors

I'm working on flutter web and faced XMLHttpRequest error while trying to fetch data from instagram(running fuction below).

```
Future<String> iconGet(String name) async {
  String url = ("https://www.instagram.com/" + name + "/");
  var data = await MetadataFetch.extract(url);
  return data!.image.toString();
}
```

I'm aware that this is issue around CORS and seems like most major solution is '--disable-web-security'.
But since website deal with customer information I can not implement method with security risks. Is there another way I can deal with this without putting customer information into risk?

Comment: Any API that you are meant to call directly from the browser will provide you a way to configure its CORS headers. If you cannot, it's not meant to be called from the browser.

Comment: thank you for reply. in the case it not meant to be called from the browser, what is best way to achieve the goal?

Comment: You create an API on *your* server and that makes requests to other servers.